# VB.net Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

Tags: vb.net

I have a function which i am getting syntax Error which I am using the same copy in other without any error .I am trying to open an Access table and read line by line and do some updates on it .

```
Function FlattenTable(Current As String, Freezefrom As Date, DateRef As Date, db As String)
    Dim date1 As Date
    Dim sql1 As String
    Dim FreezeHrs As Double
    Dim FreezeLnds As Long
    Dim rs1 As DataTable
    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand

    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & db
    }
    con.Open()

    If Freezefrom > DateRef Then
        date1 = Freezefrom
    Else
        date1 = DateRef
    End If

    sql1 = "SELECT * FROM [Hours & Landings & Cycles] WHERE [A/C] = '" & Current & "' [DATE]= " & date1 & ""
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql1, con)
    rs1 = New DataTable
    rs1.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

    FreezeHrs = rs1.Rows.Item(0).Item(3)
    FreezeLnds = rs1.Rows.Item(0).Item(4)
    '     "UPDATE [Hours & Landings & Cycles] SET [Code] = 'X' WHERE [A/C] = '" & Current & "' AND [Date]>=" & ActualEIS & " AND [Date]<=#" & DateValue(Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", EndDate)) & "#"
    sql1 = "UPDATE [Hours & Landings & Cycles] SET [HRS] = '" & FreezeHrs & "' WHERE [A/C] = '" & Current & "' AND [DATE]>='" & date1 & "'"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql1, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Function
```

rs1.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader) is a data table reader

Comment: _AND [DATE]_ The second query is syntactically correct, the first one no. Side, but very important, note. Concatenating strings to build sql command texts is the perfect recipe for disasters waiting to happen. Learn how to use parameters

Comment: Your code is very muddled. You say that you want to read line by line but you're using a `DataTable`. If you really want to read line by line then call `Read` on the data reader in a loop. Don't do that though. What you should be doing is using a data adapter to populate a `DataTable`, then modifying the data in that `DataTable`, then using the same data adapter to save the changes back in a batch.

Comment: This is yet another example of someone being told that they have a syntax error in their SQL code but not showing us that SQL code or probably even looking at it themselves. The VB code that builds your SQL code from parts is not your SQL code. As suggested, you shouldn't build it from parts anyway, but rather use parameters. If you use a data adapter then you will have no choice but to use parameters for the values that change per row at least.